# Extract href value which endsWith pdf

Tags: regex, extract

**I want to get direct links of pdf from webpage, I tried this regex pattern but did not work with me:**

```
href=.*\.pdf$
```

**data to test:**

```
<a class="btn btn-small pad-button" href="/Tests/English/english_2011_summer_A-Q_b.pdf">eng1</a><br>
<a href="english_2011_summer_A-Q_c.pdf">eng2</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the end of string `$` anchor, the href values are not at this position. I can only recommend using a parser of sort to extract these values and if you want to use regex, I propose something like the following.

```
href=(["'])([^"']+\.pdf)\1
```

The values that you want as the match result can be accessed by capturing group `#2`

Comment: works fine , how can I get only value ? without href and without quotation marks so href="english_2011_summer_A-Q_c.pdf" would be english_2011_summer_A-Q_c.pdf   ?

Comment: You would access group index 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex.

```
href=".*?([\w-]+\.pdf)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS3kI9/2)**

[image]

The idea of this regex is to look for all `href` witch contains `X.pdf` at the end.

Comment: works fine , how can I get only value ? without href and without quotation marks so href="english_2011_summer_A-Q_c.pdf" would be english_2011_summer_A-Q_c.pdf   ?

Comment: @eawedat the green highlight is the content of the capturing group which you have to access to grab its content. You can access to it using `\1`. You can check it on the link I put on the answer. Hope to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

use group 1 and get the exact value.

```
href="([^"]+\.pdf)"
```

**DEMO:**http://regex101.com/r/nR8gY4/1